# Show header/title in ChildBrowser, Phonegap/Android

Tags: android, cordova, childbrowser

I am using [ChildBrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser), which works fine to display external web pages within my PhoneGap application. My problem is that I am not able to add title/header in child web pages. Any suggestions?

What i tried so far

Instead of `toolbar.addView(edittext);` I added

```
final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(ctx.getContext()); 
rowTextView.setText(myTitle); 
toolbar.addView(rowTextView);
```

But it looks like I also need to pass myTitle variable to execute method
so that inside PluginResult execute() I can use something like

```
result = this.showWebPage(args.getString(0), args.optJSONObject(1), myTitle);
```

Can I add the same sample of code of yours for iOS?

Comment: In your js code you need to do something like `cb.showWebPage(url, {showLocationBar:true}, myTitle);` so that in the Java code you do: `result = this.showWebPage(args.getString(0), args.optJSONObject(1), args.getString(2));` As for iOS, I wouldn't know how to do it, as I don't do Objective-C...

Comment: My modified version of ChildBrowser is up on GitHub with a sample project. https://github.com/dda/slavebrowser/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to "upgrade" ChildBrowser: somewhere around line 340 there's this code: `webview.setWebViewClient(client);`. Replace it with the following:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+"var t=document.head.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];t.innerHTML="+myNewTitle+"})()");
    }
});
```

You'll have to tweak also the options reading code of `showWebPage()` to set `myNewTitle`. But after that, you should be good to go.

**EDIT:**

Basically I decided that -- for my use at least, and probably yours -- the toolbar as it stands wasn't needed. Originally, I tweaked ChildBrowser so that I could do Google oAuth2 painlessly, by sending back the full HTML source back to the JS code. I definitely don't need a toolbar, as the user is going where Google wants it to, period. I had to hack stuff off the code, and the original author could be pissed at what I did with his code... Here's a checklist:

```
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class ChildBrowser extends Plugin {
  **public String zeTitle;**

//  private EditText edittext;
private TextView edittext;
```

All references to `EditText` have to be changed to `TextView`.

```
result = this.showWebPage(args.getString(0), args.optJSONObject(1)**, args.getString(2)**);
```

You will need to change stuff in the .js file too.

```
public String showWebPage(final String url, JSONObject options**, String myNewTitle**) {
  if (options != null) {
    showLocationBar = options.optBoolean("showLocationBar", true);
  }
  **zeTitle=myNewTitle;**
```

Comment out all the `ImageButton` related code.

```
edittext = new TextView(ctx.getContext()); // insread of EditText
```

Comment out the `edittext.setOnKeyListener`

```
// edittext.setText(url);
edittext.setText(zeTitle);
edittext.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 24);
edittext.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
edittext.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
edittext.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

Add to the toolbar only what's needed:

```
// toolbar.addView(back);
// toolbar.addView(forward);
toolbar.addView(edittext);
// toolbar.addView(close);
```

Finally:

```
public class ChildBrowserClient extends WebViewClient {
// EditText edittext;
  TextView edittext;

/**
 * Constructor.
 * 
 * @param mContext
 * @param edittext 
 */
public ChildBrowserClient(TextView mEditText) {
//  this.edittext = mEditText;
}
```

In the JS code:

```
cb.showWebPage(YOUR_URL, {showLocationBar:true}, YOUR_TITLE);
```

You should be good to go. I'll put up an updated version of the ChildBrowser I use on GitHub.

Comment: well thnx for your help. 
It was useful. one trouble i am facing with the above solution is - inside execute function there is call to showWebPage
result = this.showWebPage(..);
so looks like i need to tweak the parameters of execute function also.

can you provide hints on how to do that?

Comment: Also i cannot see title bar/title after applying above solution.
Am i missing something?

Many thnx.

Comment: Come back later to approve ;-)

Comment: Let me look at your questions and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I have done something similar to you, and I got it working. See my updated answer.